# Joining tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Sorry for bad title, but I don't know what is should be.

I want to join two tables but the number of line should be same as table one.

Here are my tables

```
====Table 1=====

| Name | IdCardNo |
===============
| Peter | 1234 |
| Mary | 5678 |
===============

==========Table 2=========
| IdCardNo | phoneNo | Job |
=========================
|1234|11111111|Student|
|1234|11111111|Waiter|
|5678|22222222|Student|
=========================
```

Here is the result i want

```
Peter|1234|11111111|
Mary|5678|22222222|
```

However if i do `SELECT NAME, PhoneNo FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.IdCardNo=Table2.IdCardNo`
I get this

```
Peter|1234|11111111|
Peter|1234|11111111|
Mary|5678|2222222|
```

I know I can do GROUP BY NAME but I don't think it is a good idea.

What query should I use?

I think `SELECT DISTINCT...` is the thing I want. Thank you!

Comment: Is every person guaranteed to have a number?

Comment: what is the logic of `Mary` having `11111111` as phoneNo in the expected result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

> The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct
>   (different) values.

Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME, PhoneNo 
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN 
Table2 on Table1.IdCardNo=Table2.IdCardNo
```

Maybe you might want to reconsider the design of the tables. Unless a different (possible) number is required per instance of `table2`, you might want to store the number in `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result is ambiguous

```
Mary|5678|11111111|
```

I suppose should be

```
Mary|5678|22222222|
```

This could be achieved as

```
select 
t1.Name,
t1.IdCardNo,
t2.phoneNo
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.IdCardNo = t2.IdCardNo
group by t1.Name,t1.IdCardNo,t2.phoneNo
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct t1.NAME, t1.idCardNo, t2.PhoneNo FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.IdCardNo=t2.IdCardNo

Distinct will skip identical rows in the result set!

Answer (score 0):

'Select distinct' will only populate the joined table with unique values. Try that and let me know.